# Get current page URL using app script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I am trying to develop an add-on for Google Docs. I need to get the URL of the current page/document (not the URL of the document obtained from "DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getUrl()").

Alternatively, How to get the extra_par value when I open a document in app script

> https://docs.google.com/open?id=#doc_id#&extra_par=value

Comment: What happens when you leave off extra_par?

Comment: I want to open a document and pass a value to the document. So I am using the extra_par parameter. Is there any way to access the value of extra param using app script or is there any other workaround to achieve this.